# Access sql to retrieve counts of values meeting a condition

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

I'm trying to write a query in Access that will return a count of values for each site in a table where the value exceeds a specified level, but also, for sites that have no values exceeding that level, return a specified value, such as `"NA"`.

I've tried `Iif`, `Switch`, `Union`, sub queries, querying a different query, but no luck. I can get all the counts exceeding the level, or all sites with `"NA"` correct but showing total count for the rest, not just count above the level.

For example, in the table below, assuming level > 10, Houston = "NA", Detroit = 2, Pittsburgh PA = 3. I just can't get both sides of the query to work.

Apologize in advance for poor formatting.

```
+-----------------+-------+
|     1. Site     | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
|  2. Houston     |    10 |
|  3. Houston     |     3 |
|  4. Houston     |     0 |
|  5. Detroit     |    15 |
|  6. Detroit     |     7 |
|  7. Detroit     |     4 |
|  8. Detroit     |    12 |
|  9. Pittsburgh  |    23 |
|  10. Pittsburgh |     2 |
|  11. Pittsburgh |    18 |
|  12. Pittsburgh |    12 |
+-----------------+-------+
```

Comment: Can you post some of your querys?

Comment: It's generally wise to post the SQL you've tried, results your getting, and the results you expect to get along with sample data.  This helps us understand your question and what you're trying to do without asking a bunch of additional questions.

Comment: Part of the problem is data type 'NA' isn't numeric whereas count is and a column can't be both numeric and character; just one or the other..  would 0 work just as well as NA?

Comment: I'm using NA rather than 0 because 0 implies no value present (the values are detected chemical amounts) whereas NA indicates none found, but the chemical may be present at levels below test detection limits. Small difference, but is our workplace standard for reporting.

Comment: Then you'll need to cast the sum/count to varchar in order to support NA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution is to use conditional aggregation, as follows :

```
SELECT site, SUM(IIf(value > 10, 1, 0)) AS value
FROM mytable
GROUP BY site
```

This approach should be more efficient than self-joining the table, since it requires to scan the table only once.

The `SUM(IIf ...)` is a handy construct to count how many records satisfy a given condition.

NB : it is generally not a good idea to return two different data types in the same column (in your use case, either a number or string `'NA'`). Most RDBMS do not allow that. So I provided a query that will return `0` when there are not matches, instead of `NA`. If you really want `'NA'`, you can try :

```
IIF(
    SUM(IIf(value > 10, 1, 0)) = 0, 
    'NA', 
    STR(SUM(IIf(value > 10, 1, 0)))
) AS value
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=97b5e011a6f3bac57984899ce73e84f6)**, with your sample data returns :

```
site       | value
:--------- | ----:
Detroit    |     2
Houston    |     0
Pittsburgh |     3
```

Comment: @Rene : right. I changed the query to use `IIf` instead... Thanks for pointing this out !

Answer (score 0):

1. Get a list of all sites independant of the counts (SiteList derived table below)
2. LEFT Join this back to your base table (SiteValues) to get the counts for each site where it's meeting threshold.  --note should join on key which I'm not sure what is for this table.  site alone isn't enough
3. Count the values from the siteValues dataset as NULL's will get counted as 0.

WORKING [DEMO](https://rextester.com/ROO66621): 
.

```
SELECT SiteList.Site, Count(Sitevalues.Site)
FROM (SELECT site, value
      FROM TableName) SiteList
LEFT JOIN TableName SiteValues
 on SiteList.Site = SiteValues.Site
 and SiteValues.Value > 10
 and SiteValues.Value = SiteList.value
GROUP BY SiteList.Site
```

GIVING US:

```
+----+------------+------------------+
|    |    Site    | (No column name) |
+----+------------+------------------+
|  1 | Detroit    |                2 |
|  2 | Houston    |                0 |
|  3 | Pittsburgh |                3 |
+----+------------+------------------+
```

Or if you need the NA you have to cast the count to a varchar

```
SELECT SiteList.Site, case when Count(Sitevalues.Site) = 0 then 'NA' else cast(count(Sitevalues.site) as varchar(10)) end as SitesMeetingThreshold
FROM (SELECT site, value
      FROM TableName) SiteList
LEFT JOIN TableName SiteValues
 on SiteList.Site = SiteValues.Site
 and SiteValues.Value > 10
 and SiteValues.Value = SiteList.value
GROUP BY SiteList.Site
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION` like this:

```
SELECT site, count(value) AS counter
FROM sites
WHERE value > 10
GROUP BY site
UNION
SELECT s.site, 'NA' AS counter
FROM sites AS s
WHERE value <= 10
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM sites WHERE site = s.site AND value > 10  
)
GROUP BY site
```

Results:

```
site        counter
Detroit     2
Houston     NA
Pittsburgh  3
```

There is no need to convert the integer counter to `Text`, because **Access** does this implicitly for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select site,
       max(iif(value > 10, 1, 0)) as cnt_11plus
from t
group by site;
```

I think `0` is better than `N/A`.  But if you want that you'll need to convert the results to a string.

```
select site,
       iif(max(iif(value > 10, 1, 0)) > 0,
           str(max(iif(value > 10, 1, 0))),
           "N/A"
          ) as cnt_11plus
from t
group by site;
```